# query mysql database containing HTML special character with php

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

...i am not getting any further.

my database contains a column 'name' = 'John Richards'

i try to query it like:

```
$act = "John Richards";
prepareEditing($act);

function prepareEditing($act) {
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/final_ritg/includes/dbconnect.php");
$act = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $act);
$sql = "select `name`,`genre`, `members`, `story`, `image`, `contact_fname`, `contact_lname`, `contact_phone`, `contact_email` from `festival`.`act` where `name` = :name ;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $act);
$stmt->execute();

echo $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

when 'name' only contains a single word, like 'john', the function returns 1 ($act holds 'john' as well).

How do I have to prepare my query?

Edit: I am using utf8 across the board.

Edit: This is the prepare stmt I use to insert the data:
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', str_replace(' ',' ',$name));

I did so, because the query result would have been cut off at the whitespace when trying to retrieve it.

Comment: I was going to add that even though you have the variable being replaced in the query string, it should be enclosed in quotes. So rather than `"name" = :name`, you should do `"name" = ':name'`.

Comment: That's not how PDO works. Placeholders are given quotes if and when they are required. See the [prepared statements docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for more details.

Comment: Are you sure the value is literally what you're selecting against? Trailing or doubled spaces can interfere with exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my mistake was not in the php, but inside the html.

I was creating a select list from a table. because the names were unique, i used those as primary keys and as value for each select-option...those dont like whitespace.

The solution here would be to either add a numbered index to the table or to do some string-conversion (but that would cause a lot of extra work preparing the string for the query) I dont yet know how I would be going over this.

Anyways, maybe another beginner runs into the same trap and finds this useful.